# For LongSparseArray, what Long value does setValueAt(int index, E value) method set as key

Tags: android

For an empty `LongSparseArray`, while using `setValueAt(int index, E value)` if the `index` is more than the size of the sparse array ,what it will do? If it will not crash, then what will be the `key`?

Comment: it will crash !

Answer (score 0):

If key not found it returns `null`.

```
public E get(long key) {
    return get(key, null);
}

public E get(long key, E valueIfKeyNotFound) {
    int i = ContainerHelpers.binarySearch(mKeys, mSize, key);

    if (i < 0 || mValues[i] == DELETED) {
        return valueIfKeyNotFound;
    } else {
        return (E) mValues[i];
    }
}
```

If you call setValueAt it simply overrides previous value.

```
public void setValueAt(int index, E value) {
if (mGarbage) {
         gc();
    }

    mValues[index] = value;
}
```